# How to change order of action bar menu items

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am using Action Bar Sherlock. I have a problem with the arrangement of the icons in action bar.

From the image below the icons should be interchanged I tried all the way but couldnt find the solution.

Here is my code

```
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "CREATE").setIcon(R.drawable.img_yo_create)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    SubMenu submenus = menu.addSubMenu("SORT");
    submenus.add(2, 2, 2, "CARDS ADDED BY ME");
    submenus.add(2, 3, 3, "CARDS FROM MERCHANT");
    submenus.add(2, 4, 4, "ALL CARDS");
    submenus.add(2, 5, 5, "HELP .?");
    MenuItem subitem = submenus.getItem();
    subitem.setIcon(R.drawable.img_sorting);
    subitem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return;
}
```

[image: How to interchange these icons by changing the above code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set an order to your Submenu when you call:

> SubMenu submenus = menu.addSubMenu("SORT");

Take a look through [docs for menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html). Then take some time to look into the [getOrder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getOrder%28%29)

Since they have set constants you should use for your order, not just 1 as you did with your CREATE MenuItem you should really read that first.

You should call: [addSubMenu(int, int, int, CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#addSubMenu%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Example (I have not tried this):

> SubMenu submenus = menu.addSubMenu(2,2,2,"SORT");

Comment: Should be the same constants and methods in ABS. Try it and if it's not the same or doesn't work I will revise my answer.

Comment: First time it shows same order but next it changes its fine. But the click event takes automatically for the 2nd case

Comment: I edited it to `SubMenu submenus = menu.addSubMenu(2,12,12,"SORT");` it works now is it the right way to do

Comment: The third int in all menu constructors is the order. You should use Constants from the source code. For instance CATEGORY_SYSTEM for CREATE and CATEGORY_SECONDARY for SORT. They are all at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getOrder()